# See all of the shared files in a Dropbox account

Tags: dropbox, sharing

Is there a way to see all of the shared files in my Dropbox account?

I'd like to see which folders I've shared with people either by inviting them or just by sharing a link to that folder/file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking links in the sidebar worked

[image: links in dropbox sidebar]